# Are Add-On 10gb Nics Legit?

Tags: networking, nic

Sorry if this is product specific but I'm not sure where else to ask

Are these AddOn nics legitimate 10gbE, or does anyone have any experience with them.  There about 1/100th of the price of the intels.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833516173
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833516120

I'm pretty skeptical given that there are no reviews, however its still a bit of a niche market.

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally we don't do product recommendation-like questions here but this is an easy one.

They're both 1 Gbps NICs, not 10Gbps models - no idea why they're listed that way but even the most cursory investigation makes it clear these are 1 Gbps ok.

Comment: That's what I figured.  If something seems to good to be true and all that.  I just don't understand why 10gb cards are still so expensive :(

Comment: because they can be :)

Answer (score 1):

They're both actually just gigabit. No 10GBe here.